# itext7 how to consider rotation angle in TextPlusYExtractionStrategy

Tags: text, position, itext, landscape

The text positioning (y) is determined by the TextPlusYExtractionStrategy perfectly when the rotation angle is 0 (portrait). In case of rotation angle is 90 degree (landscape) the position y provided from left to right instead of top to bottom. How to consider the rotation to get the text position y in when the page is 90 degree.

Comment: Please add some code or test case so people can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Related question & answer: ["How to get the text position from the pdf page in iText 7"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43787066/1729265).

Comment: In the referenced answer the **y** value is determined in the line `float chunkY = chunk.getLocation().getStartLocation().get(Vector.I2);` but `chunk.getLocation()` offers much more information on location and direction of the chunk text. You have to use that information to improve the simple assignment above.

Comment: Is this same as HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy2 which is available in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815329/itext7how-to-ignore-pdf-page-rotation the above article does not work with itext 7.

Comment: Which article does not work with iText 7? And how does the question you linked relate to `HorizontalTextExtractionStrategy2`?

Comment: Hi all thanks for the information provided. The below code helped me to resolve my issue. `if(rotation == 90){
              chunkY = chunk.getLocation().getStartLocation().get(Vector.I1);
             }`  Constructor of TextPlusYExtractionStrategy  can take the rotation angle, and use the Vector.I1 which is x corordinate of the chunk.

Comment: @RaghuP Please make that an actual answer you can eventually accept.

Answer (score 1):

The below code helped me to resolve my issue.

`if(rotation == 90){
    chunkY = chunk.getLocation().getStartLocation().get(Vector.I1); 
}`
 Constructor of **TextPlusYExtractionStrategy** can take the rotation angle, and use the Vector.I1 which is x co-ordinate of the chunk.
The issue will solve only the landscape (rotation=90) issue to find the Y coordinate of the search text.